# Vim: Search for Files with Autocomplete

Tags: vim, file-search

I found this plugin:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Find_files_in_subdirectories

to be really useful to find a file(s) using a wild card. For example, I can execute

```
:Find edit*.php
```

and it will find all the PHP files starting with the word edit. What I would really like to have is to somehow index all the files in my working directory so that I can press the  key and Vim will auto complete the name for me according to the existing files in that directory. Any idea if this is possible?

Actually, the second part of this question is do you know whether this is possible in Linux terminal? It saves much time to be able to index all the files in your complicated project so that you can go to them quickly.

Regards,
Rafid

Comment: it doesn't complete when you write `:e edit<Tab>` by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Regarding the first part of the question, I strongly suggest you try out [Command-T](https://wincent.com/products/command-t) (but note it requires ruby support)
- Regarding the second part, I'm no expert but I know that for example that [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/zsh_19.html) has a highly configurable completion system. If you just want to list the php files in your project, have a look into the `find` command.

Comment: The Command-T plugin seems to be very useful, but it needs Vim to be built with Ruby support also, how can I know that, and how can I install it if it is not installed?

Comment: The documentation is pretty good : http://git.wincent.com/command-t.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/README.txt. To check for ruby support, run `--version` and verify that a "+ruby" appears in the information displayed.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but when I try to compile the C extension, I got this error: "extconf.rb:24:in `require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError) from extconf.rb:24". Any idea?

Comment: I got it, it seems to be some kind of problem with Ruby on Ubuntu. I had to install "ruby1.8-dev" in addition to "ruby" (or probably "ruby1.8-dev" is enough, not sure), and then I could execute the make command. Hey man, the tool is very brilliant, that is exactly what I was looking for :-) It could be great if I kind find a similar tool for Linux terminal. Cheers man.

Comment: I have marked your answer as the "accepted answer", so could you please just add my comment about Ubuntu to help other users figure it out easily, rather than having to dig through our comments. This way, they will vote for you :-)